# How would I make the 3 circles alternate without them going on at the same time. DON'T USE CSS

Tags: javascript, html

how would I make these three circles not change colour at the same time as each other? E.g. one colour change wouldn't overlap another? So yellow/purple goes first, then orange and black and finally green and black. I just don't want the change to overlap each other, I would like it go one by one.

```
     var circle = new Konva.Circle({
       x: 300,
       y: 120,
       sides: 3,
       radius: 50,
       fill: 'yellow',
       stroke: 'black',
       strokeWidth: 4
     });

       setInterval(function() {
       var fill = circle.fill() == 'yellow' ? 'purple' : 'yellow';
       circle.fill(fill);
       layer.draw();
     },1000);

       layer.add(circle);

       var circle2 = new Konva.Circle({
       x: 300,
       y: 230,
       sides: 3,
       radius: 50,
       fill: 'red',
       stroke: 'black',
       strokeWidth: 4
     });

       setInterval(function() {
       var fill = circle2.fill() == 'black' ? '#ffba00' : 'black';
       circle2.fill(fill);
       layer.draw();
     },1000);

       layer.add(circle2);

      var circle3 = new Konva.Circle({
       x: 300,
       y: 340,
       sides: 3,
       radius: 50,
       fill: 'blue',
       stroke: 'black',
       strokeWidth: 4
     });

   setInterval(function() {
   var fill = circle3.fill() == 'black' ? 'green' : 'black';
   circle3.fill(fill);
   layer.draw();
 },1000);

   layer.add(circle3);

   stage.add(layer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want each circle to alternate colors, each for one second? The following will just draw each circle once and then go to the next one.

Instead of three separate functions for drawing the circle, you can have one that takes the circle to draw:

```
var drawCircle = function(circle) {
  circle.fill(circle.fill);
  layer.draw();
};
```

Then you will need a routine to cycle through the three circles and trigger completion:

```
var getNextCircle = function(prevCircle) {
  if (!prevCircle) return circle;
  if (prevCircle === circle) return circle2;
  if (prevCircle === circle2) return circle3;
  return undefined;
};
```

Now a routine to initiate once per second - setTimeout() is usually more useful than setInterval():

```
var prevCircle = undefined;
var drawCircles = function() {
  var nextCircle = getNextCircle(prevCircle);
  if (nextCircle) {
    drawCircle(nextCircle);
    prevCircle = nextCircle;
    if (prevCircle) {
      setTimeout(drawCircles, 1000);
    }
  }
};
```

Finally, you can kick it off:

```
drawCircles();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code you could simply increase `setInterval()`'s value on `circle2` & 3 by `1000` (1 second - or adjust as desired):

```
var circle = new Konva.Circle({
  x: 300,
  y: 120,
  sides: 3,
  radius: 50,
  fill: 'yellow',
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 4
});

setInterval(function() {
  var fill = circle.fill() == 'yellow' ? 'purple' : 'yellow';
  circle.fill(fill);
  layer.draw();
}, 1000);

layer.add(circle);

var circle2 = new Konva.Circle({
  x: 300,
  y: 230,
  sides: 3,
  radius: 50,
  fill: 'red',
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 4
});

setInterval(function() {
  var fill = circle2.fill() == 'black' ? '#ffba00' : 'black';
  circle2.fill(fill);
  layer.draw();
}, 2000);

layer.add(circle2);

var circle3 = new Konva.Circle({
  x: 300,
  y: 340,
  sides: 3,
  radius: 50,
  fill: 'blue',
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 4
});

setInterval(function() {
  var fill = circle3.fill() == 'black' ? 'green' : 'black';
  circle3.fill(fill);
  layer.draw();
}, 3000);

layer.add(circle3);

stage.add(layer);
```